# Data from Excel file is not being displayed using odbc in php

Tags: microsoft-excel, php, odbc

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$connect = odbc_connect('Test','EWF','EWF');

$query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];";
$result = odbc_exec($connect,$query);
$row = odbc_fetch_array($result);
if (!$row){
    $test = odbc_result($row,'Column');
    echo $test;
}
```

A blank page is appearing but no data??
    ?>

Comment: This looks like a programming problem. You might get better answers over at https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

If that is the actual connection string you are using, it is wrong. You need to declare what driver you are using and then provide the driver the arguments it expects. Here is an example:

```
$excelFile = "your file name here.xls";
$excelDir = "path\to\that\file\";
odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
```

PHP DOCUMENTATION:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Comment: sorry but I get this error when  I try your way= SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. By the way I have configured my System DNS as Test. That's why connection is not failing ...

Comment: The server needs Excel to be installed in order to have the Excel driver required to read the file. The file also needs to exist in a path that is reachable by the server. If you need more help please be more specific about what you are doing. Give details about where everything is and what you are trying to do.